# Don't remove empty p (<p>&nbsp;</p>) tags from Wordpress on page load

Tags: wordpress

In my basic Wordpress editor I have an article with html-code like this:

```
<h4><b>Hello!</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>my text</p>
```

When that article page is loaded I always see only this:

```
<h4><b>Hello!</h4>
<p>my text</p>
```

How can I force WordPress to stop removing empty `p` tags?

I have tried two methods and neither one worked:

1.I tried to add such lines to 'functions.php' of my theme:

```
 remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
 remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

2.I tried to add slashes to all `add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );` in 'wp-includes/default-filters.php'.

None of these helped. Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to not lose `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

1. Use only text editor: every time you're switching from `Text` editor to `Visual` you'll lose changes.
2. Use filter:

   ```
   function prevent_deleting_pTags($init){
       $init['wpautop'] = false;

       return $init;
   }

   add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'prevent_deleting_pTags');
   ```

   Code goes to `functions.php` file of your active theme.
3. Add some `id/class/data-` to your `p` tag:

   ```
   <p class="my_class">&nbsp;</p>
   <p id="my_id">&nbsp;</p>
   <p data-save="my_save">&nbsp;</p>
   ```

Comment: 1. Is not a solutions.

Comment: 2. The code doesn't work for me :( Seems like 'functions.php' is ignoring.

Comment: @KirMazur 1. and 3. options must be clear. about second: do you sure, that the code you added to the functions.php file of `active` theme?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way your theme handles empty paragraphs. If the extra paragraphs are for spacing, the best thing to do would be to add a css id or class to the last paragraph and add the proper spacing with margin or padding.

I wouldn't add empty paragraphs so I have never had this problem, however I have seen some themes that automatically remove the `<p>` and `</p>` if the paragraph does not have a class or id. You could try the following to force WordPress to leave the paragraphs as is:

```
<h4><b>Hello!</h4>
<p class="blank">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="blank">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="texthere">my text</p>
```

Also, that `<b>` has to be closed eventually...

Answer (score 0):

I am using the "TinyMCE Advanced" plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) to prevent "automatic handling" of `<p>` tags in the editor.

That way I see the `<p>` tags which are automatically created in "visual mode" also in the "text mode" tab and can change back and forth between the two modes without loosing any `<p>` tags, including those which only contain a `&nbsp;` entity and therefore create an empty line.

Comment: Sometimes I really need to add extra space and I want to be sure it will be extra space there. But now WordPress removing it every time when page is loading. It's never the same as in editor.

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162376/how-to-stop-editor-removing-space-nbsp-in-the-beginning-of-the-paragraph), use `<b>&nbsp;</b>` to preserve the whitespace. As they state, it's hacky but it works.